# PagedListAdapter: Weird run time behaviours

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am using PageListAdapter in a fragment dedicated for chatting(just like in any modern messaging application). I initially used RecyclerView only, but it's very jittery. After that I searched further and came across PagedListAdapter, but, It's here with its unique limitations and bugs. it's more jittery and weird scrolling behaviour. Whenever the data is changed in DB which is loaded using RxJava Flowable, most of the views are recreated as all the messages/views in RecyclerView starts flickering, the scroll position automatically changes and scrolls to somewhere in middle.

So, basically I have these questions:

How to start the view with last page of PagedListAdapter?
How to prevent PagedListAdapter from auto-scrolling?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using `RecyclerView` inside the `MotionLayout` (from beta3/beta4).
I was using `MotionLayout` to achieve a swipeable overlay (from bottom in portrait and from left in horizontal mode).
In horizontal mode, updating the RecyclerView worked OK because in horizontal mode, the overlay was taking up the entire screen, and so did the RecyclerView.
But in portrait mode, I needed to have the overlay swiped only up to a half of screen, hence, the `RecyclerView` was not full screen.

In this case, the entire view was changing its size when the `RecyclerView` was updated, creating a jumpy list (when new chat message inserted, the list would jump to another position).

Still haven't figured it out why exactly, and I can't confirm it's because of the MotionLayout, but its the main suspect.

My solution to it was to fixate the height so the list wouldn't change size on update. I've overriden the `getHeight` function of the `LayoutManager` and set a fixed size that I got in `onViewCreated()` of the fragment.
Also, you need to keep this layout listener to have the size changed if the keyboard appears.

```
requireView().viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            if (initialHeight != view.height) {
                initialHeight = view.height
                chatLayoutManager.requestLayout()
            }
        }
chatLayoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), VERTICAL, true) {
            override fun getHeight() = initialHeight
}
```